# Where one finds phrases such as "imbued with ambivalence"?

Tags: phrases, expressions

Where one finds phrases such as "imbued with ambivalence"?

From [Source](http://www.independent.co.uk/news/uk/home-news/judge-criticises-social-worker-over-report-which-might-as-well-have-been-written-in-a-foreign-language-10434202.html), some other phrases :
"having many commonalities emanating from their histories", 
"issues had a significant interplay on (her) ability" and 
"I asked her to convey a narrative"

What kind of talk is that? What do these (archaic?) uncommon phrases are called?

Comment: One can easily invent them.  Eg, take "I asked her to tell a story" and replace "tell" and "story" with synonyms.  But in inbred office environments one often finds that phrases such as "commonalities emanating from their histories" take a life of their own.

Comment: This is typically the result of someone consulting a thesaurus and substituting synonyms for nouns and verbs.The practice is often fueled by the insecurity of those who have read little and therefore do not recognize bad writing when they see it, and wrongly associate big words with good ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an example of [high-sounding](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/high-sounding) (pompous)  speech:

> - Pretentiously impressive; pompous: high-sounding oratory.

(AHD)

also [rhetoric](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/Rethoric),  in its negative connotation:

> - excessive use of ornamentation and contrivance in spoken or written discourse; bombast.

(Collins)

Comment: also 'bullshit' 1. 


stupid... talk or writing; nonsense.-  https://www.google.co.uk/?gws_rd=ssl#q=bullshit+definition

Comment: @chaslyfromUK - mmmm, that might be but it depends on personal judgement. Literally it is a way to express ideas/concepts etc.  using high-flow language.